# Pass/give something other than a form to the POST request

Tags: forms, express, http, post, get

I'm doing a form where when you select an option (with the  and  tag), a text below the form change according to the choice.
I would like to have this text along with my form data when send to a POST request.
I'm using Express and EJS.

Btw I also have GET parameters and would like the same thing as the text, any thoughts ?

Can you help me please ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Whatever code you have that changes the text according to your choice, can also set a hidden form value in your form to the same value.  That [hidden form value](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp) will not display to the end user in the browser, but will be sent with the form as part of the POST (as another value of the form).

Here's an example of a hidden form element from that previous linked reference:

```
<input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="3487">
```

If this is inside your `<form>`, you can then change it with your Javascript to whatever you want it to and it will be automatically sent to your server as one of your form values when the form is POSTed to your server, but won't be shown to the user because of the `type="hidden"`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'll try it

Comment: @Xeway - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure.